# Json same name different data type Moshi Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

This is my model class and i have these types of json to convert in to this model. How i can do that with Moshi (Using Retrofit)

```
data class(var Id:Int, var image:List<String>)

{"Id":188, "image":"\/posts\/5fd9aa6961c6dd54129f51d1.jpeg"}

{"Id":188, "image":["\/posts\/5fd9aa6961c6dd54129f51d1.jpeg","\/posts\/5fd9aa6961c6dd54129f51d1.jpeg"]}
```

Comment: Can you specify, if both types of JSON are returned by same request, or there are 2 separate requests and each return one type of JSON?

Comment: If either of these responses is possible from a single API call, then this will require a custom serializer to detect the type and then format it appropriately to the proper data class.

Comment: This both can be seen in a single request. Can you please give an example of that custom serializer??

Comment: @SartajRoshan check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a bit unorthodox, in general I would avoid designing JSONs with matching field names but different signature. Anyway, the solution:

Define your model as follow:

```
data class MyModel(
    @Json(name = "Id") val Id: Long,
    @Json(name = "image") val images: List<String>
)
```

Then, you will have to create a custom adapter for it:

```
class MyModelAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(model: MyModel): String {
        // MyModel is data class so .toString() should convert it to correct Json format with
        // image property as list of image path strings
        return model.toString()
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): MyModel = with(reader) {
        // We need to manually parse the json
        var id: Long? = null
        var singleImage: String? = null
        val imageList = mutableListOf<String>()

        beginObject()
        while (hasNext()) {
            // iterate through the JSON fields
            when (nextName()) {
                "Id" -> id = nextLong() // map the id field
                "image" -> { // map the image field
                    when (peek()) {
                        JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY -> {
                            // the case where image field is an array
                            beginArray()
                            while(hasNext()) {
                                val imageFromList = nextString()
                                imageList.add(imageFromList)
                            }
                            endArray()
                        }
                        JsonReader.Token.STRING -> {
                            // the case where image field is single string
                            singleImage = nextString()
                        }
                        else -> skipValue()
                    }
                }
                else -> skipValue()
            }
        }
        endObject()
        id ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Id should not be null")
        val images = if (singleImage != null) {
            listOf(singleImage)
        } else {
            imageList
        }
        MyModel(Id = id, images = images)
    }
}
```

Then, add the adapter to your moshi builder:

```
Moshi.Builder()
    .add(MyModelAdapter())
    .build()
```

That should do it. For complete code base, you can check my demo I just created that mirrors your case:

https://github.com/phamtdat/MoshiMultipleJsonDemo